# Add node modules to puppeteer as a script tag?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Is something this possible with Puppeteer? If so, how?

```js
await page.addScriptTag({ url: 'my-node-module' })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the Node module is browser compatible? If so, add it like any other script file, pointing to its bundled .js.

Comment: You can also use `type: "module"`.